# Always start vertical ScrollBar from the top

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

```
nspQuestionArea = new NScrollPane(); 
nspQuestionArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

nspQuestionArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

nspQuestionArea.setViewportView(getNpQuestionArea());    
//where getNpQuestionArea() return a panel    
nspQuestionArea.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);             
nspQuestionArea.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);    
nspQuestionArea.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(5);    
nspQuestionArea.setOpaque(false);
```

if i open the panel,the vertical scrollbar starts from the middle of the panel,i need to start the scrollbar always from the top.

is there any method to do like that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there are methods to do that but the viewport view may automatically change that. For example, an editable JTextPane will automatically try to display the caret location and could trigger scrolling automatically. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can carefuly review your issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what an `NScrollPane` is, or what the component returned from `getNpQuestionArea()` is, but it looks like they're probably just an extension of `JComponent`s. In that case, you can probably call the following...

```
getNpQuestionArea().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,0,0,0));
```

Also, assuming that `NScrollPane` is an extension of `JScrollPane`, if you pass in the `getNpQuestionArea()` into the constructor of the `NScrollPane`, I believe it should automatically be at the top. So, something like this...

```
nspQuestionArea = new NScrollPane(getNpQuestionArea());
```

If you parse the `JComponent` into the `NScrollPane` constructor, I believe it positions the scrollbar at the top-left of the `JComponent`. However, if you add the `JComponent` later by calling `setViewportView()`, it positions it centrally by default. It has something to do with the way that the `JComponent`s are layed-out when generating the display - if you add it in the constructor, it lays out the `NScrollPane` to the correct size and location for the `JComponent` that you pass to it. However, if you create a default `NScrollPane` and only give it the `JComponent` later, it just creates a `NScrollPane` at a default size, rather than fitting it appropriately to the `JComponent`.

Give both of these a try and see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

setCaretPosition(0) worked for me